# Python xarray: Extract first and last time value within each month of a timeseries

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, python-xarray

EDIT 2016-01-24: This behavior was from a bug in xarray (at the time known as 'xray').  See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159891/1706640) by skc below.

I have an `xarray.DataArray` comprising daily data spanning multiple years.  I want to compute the time tendency of that data for each month in the timeseries.  I can get the numerator, i.e. the change in the quantity over each month, using `resample`.  Supposing `arr` is my `xarray.DataArray` object, with the time coordinate named `'time'`:

```
data_first = arr.resample('1M', 'time' how='first')
data_last = arr.resample('1M', 'time' how='last')
```

Then `data_last - data_first` gives me the change in that variable over that month.

However, this doesn't work on the `time=arr.time` object itself: both `'first'` and `'last'` kwarg values yield the same value, which is the last day of that month.  Also, I can't use the `groupby` methods, because doing so with `time.month` groups all the Januaries together, all the Februaries together, etc., when I want the first and last time value within each individual month in the timeseries.

Is there a simple way to do this in xarray?  I suspect yes, but I'm new to the package and am failing miserably.

Comment: skc's answer here is definitely the right work around for now. However, this behavior is definitely a bug -- it's the same cause as these issues: https://github.com/xray/xray/issues/634 https://github.com/xray/xray/issues/367

Looks like I need to prioritize that refactor :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `'time'` is a coordinate in the DataArray you provided, **for the moment** it is not possible<sup>1</sup> preform resample directly upon it. A possible workaround is to create a new DataArray with the time coordinate values as a variable (still linked with the same coordinate `'time'`)

If `arr` is the DataArray you are starting from I would suggest something like this:

```
time = xray.DataArray(arr.time.values, coords=[arr.time.values], dims=['time'])
time_first = time.resample('1M', 'time', how='first')
time_last = time.resample('1M', 'time', how='last')
time_diff = time_last - time_first
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not the intended behavior -- see Stephan's comment above.

**Update:** [Pull request 648](https://github.com/xray/xray/pull/648) has fixed this issue, so there should no longer be a need to use a workaround.